# Can't call a function from another file in python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module

In vscode i have two files in the same folder (main.py and helloworld.py), main importing helloworld and using a function from it, but i get the error "NameError: name 'displayText' is not defined" even though it is a function. The code in main.py is

```
from helloworld import *

displayText()
```

and the code in helloworld is

```
def displayText():
    print("Hi")
```

I know it is an error with vscode because i tried testing it in repl and it worked fine.

Comment: Is that ```helloworld.txt```? Just curious because you did not mention the extension

Comment: its helloworld.py

Comment: You should add more details. Are you able to run the function from `helloworld.py`?

Comment: @Bean Can you provide a screenshot of it? It should not have problems with your description.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention you placed two files in the same folder. it is necessary to check that the file name **“helloworld.py”** and Imported file name are identical. For your concern please check if the two file extensions are **".py"**. The error message is shown here the program can not find the function 'displayText'.